# List button function

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5

I was searching for a function name of the symbol in the screen

http://jesperbylund.com/wp-content/uploads//2012/01/image-2.png the icon  in the navigationBar.

How do you call that icon and the function of it in de Path app? A sort of navigation? (see screen)

Answer (score 0):

I would have said menuIcon, and menuPanel.

I don't think there is a proper name for this kind of navigation system yet.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a `UIBarButtonItem` using the `appearance` method to set the background image for the button.

As to what it's called, well, you can call it whatever you like - menu button?